# scan list for a range of conditions

Tags: python, search, conditional-statements, limits

Having the elements:

- data list: L
- target value: target
- Bounds: # a positive number
- method: search_combination(data,target) which returns a list

I want put these together in a method that calls search_combination over and over,and returns the result of that method when a condition is met.
the new method tries "target" first in search_combination (and returns result if condition is met), then tries target+-range(bound) and returns the value for condition nearest target.
**the main problem is making a code for trying target+-range(bound).**

here is what I have atm:

```
def main(data,target,bound):
    result=search_combination(data,target)
    if result !=[]: #condition is met
       return [result,target]
    else:
       for i in range(bound):
           temp=i
           result=search_combination(data,target+temp)
           if result !=[]:
              temp=target+temp
              break
           result=search_combination(data,target-temp)
           if result !=[]:
              temp=target-temp
              break
       return [result,temp]
```

how can this code be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to alternate the +/-, you can do something like this

```
   import math

   ...

   for i in range(bound):
       temp=i
       emptyFound = False
       for j in range(2):
         result=search_combination(data,target+(math.pow(-1, j) * temp))
         if result !=[]:
            emptyFound = True
            break
       if emptyFound == True:
         break;
   return [result,temp]
```

Comment: thanks for comment. but "bound" represents "max distance from target". and the for loop tries "one step at a time", trying both directions in each step. if that makes sense. I'm looking for a shorter approach that doesn't need copying lines of code